# SQL SERVER EXPRESS 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql

i my developer pc with the 2008 express on 1 site and the server somewhere else
is it possible to connect and view the server's DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all you need to do is install and launch the SQL Server Management Studio and use it to connect to the remote database.

Comment: can i do it with windows authentication or only with SQL?

Comment: what if i install that managment but sent my server with windows authentication - how can i change it?

Comment: If your computer and the server are on the same Windows domain then your domain account just needs to be given access to the server.  If they aren't on the same domain then you can create an account on the server with the same username and password as the account which you use on your computer.  This will allow you to use Windows Authentication.  You can change the server to use SQL Authentication by logging into the server as an admin and right clicking on the instance and selecting properties then select the security tab.